# How can I install Roland Fantom-G6 via USB

Tags: midi

On the Roland pages there are only drivers wor Windows and OSX. How can I run it on Linux?

I would like to connect it via USB and use it as external Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

The Fantom-G series is supported since kernel version 3.11.

You should upgrade the kernel.